# How to extract this specific text/json *only* using grep

Tags: bash, grep

So I have this json file that's an output from a  previous command:

```
{
    "upload": {
        "status": "INITIALIZED", 
        "contentType": "application/octet-stream", 
        "name": "mobile.apk", 
        "created": 1511111178.799, 
        "url": "https://amazonaws.com/arn%358%3Aproject%3A0030e-0a929/uploads/arn%3Aaws%3??/33bgb", 
        "type": "ANDROID_APP", 
        "arn": "arn:aws:devicefarm:us-west-2:588:upload:0000-aaa-bg01-11ab11/1feebbb-1a1a"
    }
}
```

I want to extract the "arn" value, including the quotes, so the value:

```
"arn:aws:devicefarm:us-west-2:588:upload:0000-aaa-bg01-11ab11/1feebbb-1a1a"
```

Should be returned. I'll also need a separate command to extract the url value also, so the following needs to be returned:

```
"https://amazonaws.com/arn%358%3Aproject%3A0030e-0a929/uploads/arn%3Aaws%3??/33bgb"
```

So I need 2 separate commands for these values. I've tried all different combinations of grep and I've not got anything to work yet.

I only want to use grep for the command, my situation won't allow to install any tools.

Thank you!

Comment: Don't use text processing tools to process JSON stream. Use a proper syntax aware parser

Comment: What about python? Is it built-in?

Comment: In your case you just need `awk '/arn:/{print $2; exit}' jsonFile` or `awk '/arn:/{print $2; exit}' jsonFile`

Comment: grep solutions: `cat json_file | grep -oP '(?<=        "url": ).+(?=,)'` and `cat json_file | grep -oP '(?<=        "arn": ).+$'`

Answer (score 1):

There is couple of possible solutions, depending on a tool set that is available for you. 
Lets assume that bash variable `JSON` contains whole JSON structure you described in the topic.

Bash + Python:

```
ARN=`echo "$JSON" | python -c "import sys, json; print json.load(sys.stdin)['upload']['arn']"`
URL=`echo "$JSON" | python -c "import sys, json; print json.load(sys.stdin)['upload']['url']"`
```

Bash + jq:

```
URL=`echo "$JSON" | jq -r '.upload.url'`
ARN=`echo "$JSON" | jq -r '.upload.arn'`
```

Bash + grep + awk

```
URL=`echo "$JSON" | grep -Po '"url":.*?".*?"' | awk '{ print $2 }'`
ARN=`echo "$JSON" | grep -Po '"arn":.*?".*?"' | awk '{ print $2 }'`
```

Now you can do

```
echo "$ARN"
echo "$URL"
```

But as it was already mentioned by others, don't use awk, grep, sed and any other tools for text processing. Use dedicated tools for this.